# How to change element in table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm using django-template and i got for loop in my template and i want to change apperance of table to look normal

I guess i need to use some Javascript there but i dont know how to modify my table

template.html

```
<table id="contractTable" class="display normal table cell-border" cellsacing="0" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light"></p></th>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Contract</p></th>
        <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%"><p class="fw-light">Current</p></th>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Total</p></th>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Total_2</p></th>
        <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%"><p class="fw-light">% </p></th>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Type</p></th>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Files</p></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for contract in list_of_contracts %}
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">{{ contract.CounterpartyGUID }}</td>
            <td>{{ contract.ContractName }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ contract.Currency }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ contract.SumContractWithoutVAT|floatformat:0|intcomma }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ contract.SumContractWithVAT|floatformat:0|intcomma }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ contract.VAT|floatformat:0 }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ contract.ContractType }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="ref_key" value="{{ contract.ContractGUID }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="contract_name"
                           value="{{ contract.ContractName }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="object_name" value="{{ object_name }}">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Files">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That's how it looks

[image]

I want first line to be normal and other columns be normal as well

Comment: Do you mean you want to add some classes and styling to parent tr?

Comment: Do you mean to use the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property ?

Comment: I'm not rly sure about that i'm kinda new in js but i need to change apperance from td to tr in this element

Comment: you just need to add or remove classes to elements then `counter.classList.add("myclass");` or `counter.classList.remove("myclass");`

Comment: That's not how the [`before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/before) method works... It will insert the string as text, not as HTML.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what "change how td looks like" means. Do you only want to change its CSS style ?

Comment: I'll totally update my question to specify it

Comment: Why did you left first column blank in your thead? Is it for any specific purpose?

Comment: No, i dont need that ```th``` there i still need 7 th columns but without first th table is breaking

Comment: Can't you do the styling in django itself. You can add conditional using your loop counter. I don't think you even need JS here. Like {% if forloop.first %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i mentioned in the comments. You can add styling or change HTML in your template itself. You don't even need JS to handle that.
See below example for reference:

```
<table id="contractTable" class="display normal table cell-border" cellsacing="0" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Contract</p></th>
        <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%"><p class="fw-light">Current</p></th>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Total</p></th>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Total_2</p></th>
        <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%"><p class="fw-light">% </p></th>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Type</p></th>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Files</p></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for contract in list_of_contracts %}
      {% if forloop.first %} <!-- or you can use {{ forloop.counter }} as well -->
        <tr class="YOUR_CLASS" style="YOUR STYLE">
          <td class="text-center" colspan="7">{{ contract.CounterpartyGUID }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% else %}
        <tr>            
            <td>{{ contract.ContractName }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ contract.Currency }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ contract.SumContractWithoutVAT|floatformat:0|intcomma }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ contract.SumContractWithVAT|floatformat:0|intcomma }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ contract.VAT|floatformat:0 }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ contract.ContractType }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="ref_key" value="{{ contract.ContractGUID }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="contract_name"
                           value="{{ contract.ContractName }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="object_name" value="{{ object_name }}">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Files">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
      {% endif %}
        
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To access TR from TD you may use `.parent()`. actually in your code the **counter** is the TD element itself and using `.before()` will add another new element before TD element and wont modify the current TD.

Besides, `+counter+'</td></tr>'` is meaningless because `.bofore()` is working with elements which handles opening and closing tags. It is not working with html texts.

```js
var $counter=$('#counter_td')
$counter.show().parent().addClass("group fs-3").css({"background-color":"#f5f5f5"});
$counter.attr("colspan","7");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="contractTable" class="display normal table cell-border" cellsacing="0" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Somthing</p></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="counter_td" style="display: none">Something there</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

or without jquery:

```js
var counter=document.getElementById('counter_td');
counter.parentElement.classList.add("group","fs-3");
counter.parentElement.style.backgroundColor="#f5f5f5";
counter.setAttribute("colspan","7");
```

```html
<table id="contractTable" class="display normal table cell-border" cellsacing="0" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center"><p class="fw-light">Somthing</p></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="counter_td">Something there</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The question does not reference jQuery. You should point out when adding a library to make an answer work...

Comment: updated with pure js. That was because he only used .before() which is shared between js and jquery. @HereticMonkey